# Maintain button text look when zooming

Tags: css, css-float, css-frameworks

EDIT: Turns out this is fixed in macOS catalina. Bon Voyage!

How can I maintain a button's look when a user zooms in or out? The spacing between the text and edge of a button needs to stay consistent.

[image: jsfiddle of this question]

Work on the fiddle pictured here: http://jsfiddle.net/DevinRhode2/B4Usb/5/

If you set your browser zoom to 100% and remove `zoom: 1.1;` from the fiddle, you'll see buttons with fully contained and centered text - this look is the goal.

Perhaps it's easier to re-create the css for native mac-style buttons, with necessary modifications.

Fixing this, or alternatively, re-creating the identical OS X styling, will not be easy so I started a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I have cheched on chromium, firefox and IE, everything zooms just right, and no text outside the boundaries of the button can be seen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jigHu.png

Comment: Well, does the text stay in the center of the button as if there was no zoom? It you have a solution please share a link to a jsfiddle, preferably a fork of the above jsfiddle.

Comment: Thats the point that I haven't changed anything - your code just worked fine while zooming in on different browsers. I have put a link to screenshot in my previous reply. What OS and browser are you working with?

Comment: It's not actually centered if you look close enough. I exaggerated the zoom here: http://jsfiddle.net/DevinRhode2/B4Usb/5/ Are you on windows or mac, and what version?

Comment: I just followed your link and in my case it's perfectly centered. Take a look http://i.imgur.com/hajdl.png I am on windows right now, running Chromium 20.0. Also I have checked on IE 10.0 and Firefox 17.0.1. Also I have checked on my mac machine running MacOSX 10.8 with safari 6.0.2.

Comment: I concur, no problems on Chrome Windows, but the default Mac styling in Chrome OSX screws it pretty good.

Comment: Solid conclusion. If you make an edit to your answer, SO will let me remove the downvote.

Comment: *ping* if you make some edit to your answer I can remove my downvote and upvote

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed a problem using OSX on Chrome, this is due to OSX's awfully handled default styling rules for buttons.

You can fix it by adding your own background styling to the buttons:

```
#fixed {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0;
}
```

I removed the border also, as the default border for styled buttons is uuugly.

http://jsfiddle.net/B4Usb/7/